# queue socket connections in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

In a client-server architecture, i have a server that accepts connections from clients. i want the server to accept 3 simultaneous connections and the rest of the connections (when available) to be put on hold to be served in a FIFO manner. 
What would be the right way of doing this?

One possible approach that i thought of is

Making a counter and checking if its less than 3, accept, serve the client in a new thread, and increment counter. When counter is greater than 3, just accept and save the socket descriptor in a queue. When a client finishes his work, stop the thread (by joining for example) and decrement counter to allow another client to be served. If the queue is not empty pop a socket descriptor, create a thread and serve the client.

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Or you might want to have 3 worker threads, each reading connection requests from the queue.
(In general, accepting a connection and then keeping it on hold might be not the best experience from the client's point of view.)

Comment: so you mean i keep all connections in a queue and have 3 worker threads that keep popping and serving ?. oh yeah i agree with you on that but its just for practice.

Comment: Correct. This is just a simplification of the scheme you suggested (no more creating/joining threads, and the counter is not needed).

Comment: Why would you deliberately limit the usefulness of your server in this way?

Comment: I understand why the counter is not needed but, what about creating threads ? how is that not needed anymore? When a thread is done with its task and the client disconnects, shouldn't i create a new thread instead of it ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck well just because its a practice exercise. Been doing several different client-server architectures as a practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `listen` function has a backlog that you can be set, ie. it will hold all connections in a queue and when `accept` is called, the first element waiting in the queue is actually accepted, a solution from this aspect is as follows.

In an infinite loop, only accept connections as long as counter is less than a specific number(maximum number of clients to be serves simultaneously).
Declare a `mutex` that protects a counter that is incremented every time a connection is accepted. 
Declare a condition variable to b used for signaling when a thread finished his task. 
Using that condition variable and a mutex, wait if counter is more than X. 
When a thread serving a client is done with its task, decrement counter and signal the condition. Hence the infinite loop will loop again and accept an already on-hold client.

One possible implementation of this could be:

```
// global variable 
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cv;
int number_of_connected_client = 0;

// a function executed by a thread to handle each user
void *client_thread(void *arg) {

  /* some code */

  // thread is about to finish and return
  // client disconnected --> decrement number of connected clients 
  // signal that a client disconnected
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  number_of_connected_client-- ;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  return 0;
}

// infinte loop for accepting connections
while (1) {

  // serve 2 users at a time, queue the rest of the clients in the listen's queue 
  if( number_of_connected_client >= 2 ) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);      
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }

  connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL );

  // create a thread and serve the client 
  if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , client_thread, (void*)connfd) <0)
    {
     // error in creating thread
     // do something 
    }

  // client is served --> increment number of connected clients 
  else {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    number_of_connected_client ++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }

}
```

This is just an easy workaround to get things working for private testing or hw or etc... the proper way of dealing with this is a pool thread with worker threads assigned tasks as provided by Inspired's comment.